# SonarQube excluding files, directories, and generated code?

Tags: maven, sonarqube

The code base I am working with has a lot of generated code. In addition, there are also some deprecated files that I would want to exclude from SonarQube analysis. I've read up the documentation and looked at some answers on here about that, but it does not help in my case.

I have a multi-module maven project. So I have multiple projects in my workspace that are all part of a large application. Say I want to exclude this file:

`/home/username/workspace/com.mst.rtra.importing.message/bin/com/mst/rtra/importing/message/idl/parse/idlparser.java`

I don't really know how to write this in the exclusions settings on SonarQube because of how long the filepath is. Also, what if I want to exclude another file, but from a different module, say :

`/home/username/workspace/com.mst.rtra.interpreter.create/`

I am confused about I should write this in the exclusions box in project settings. Should I write the absolute file path due to the multi-module nature of this project? Or is there some other convention used?

In addition, if I want to exclude generated files from analysis, I would need to put `file:/generated-sources/` as I saw in another answer. However, after analysis, I can still view the analysis results of those files when I open up the project in SonarQube dashboard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use ant rather than maven, and an older version of the Sonar ant task at that.  But what works for us is setting a sonar.exclusions property in our build.xml, which accepts wildcards for filenames. For example:

```
<property name="sonar.exclusions" value="**/com/ex/wsdl/asvc/*.java,**/com/ex/wsdl/bsvc/*.java"/>
```

That skips analyzing all the code generated from a wsdl file for two services. You ought to be able to do something similar for maven.