# Jenkins Sonarqube Plugin Additional arguments adding space

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, space

I am trying to add the Sonarqube to our project. But there are several large js files I want to exclude. I try to use the additional arguments to exclude the file path, one of them is to exclude all the files followed by the path "sitecore Modules", when I use the command `/d:sonar.exclusions=**/sitecore modules/**/*.js,**/js/libs/**/*.js`

It gives me an error said 
`Unrecognized command line argument: modules/**/*.js,**/js/libs/**/*.js`

I think it is because the space between the two word, but I am not sure let sonarqube command recognize the space. I also make a screenshot to explain my question. [image]
[image]

Anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SonarQube excluding files, directories, and generated code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409154/sonarqube-excluding-files-directories-and-generated-code)

Comment: Please consider the below posts once:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193563/sonar-exclusions-in-pom-xml-maven-multi-module-project-works-locally-but-not
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409154/sonarqube-excluding-files-directories-and-generated-code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323276/sonarqube-exclude-a-directory